# For each value in the array change to the same image in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, image

There is an array which will increase and decrease in size and I was trying to implement something that will allow the code to go through each value in the array and perform the following code: (set the same image for each value)

```
if (something) {
myArray[0].css("background-image", "url(pictures/img.png)")
myArray[1].css("background-image", "url(pictures/img.png)")
}
```

The code above works however, it only works for the first two values, what if there is more? or less?

I was thinking of implementing forEach method so it could actually replace the image within every value, however it is not a variable as it modifies the CSS file and I am slightly confused how I could do that since I couldn't find relevant example, so here's the code I thought it might work but it doesn't

```
if (something) {
    myArray.forEach(value) {
    myArray.css("background-image", "url(pictures/img.png)")
    }
}
```

Also, it's all inside a function and jQuery has been specified already, that's why you see me using .css without $ sign

Any help appreciated

Comment: Is expected result for all elements within array to be set with same URL at `url()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loops through your array and updates each of the jQuery elements.

```
if (something) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        myArray[i].css("background-image", "url(pictures/img.png)");
    }
}
```